# Error:java: invalid source release Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA (2018.1.2). When try run anything I get this shit ["Error:java: invalid source release:"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nP5Y.png).
I can't compile anything.
I just have wasted about 3 hours to search solution on internet and nothing helps me

Output "java --version":

```
java 15.0.1 2020-10-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode, sharing)
```

my settings on IDE:

```
Settings -> Build, Exectuion, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Target bytecode version = 11
Project Structure -> Project SDK = 15.0.1
Project Structure -> Project language level = X - experimental features
Project Structure -> Modules -> Language level (root) = X - experimental features
```

I have tried change any parameter above to lower value but no result. IDE says it uses java 8, i don't know how to change it. This error kills me, help please

Comment: What SDK is set for the project and Module? https://i.imgur.com/Uufr6Yu.png

Comment: it says java vesion "15.0.1"

Comment: Is it Maven/Gradle project? Inspect pom.xml/gradle.build if so